# Fetching collections of books using ActiveResource returns an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

Fetching collections of books using activeresource.

I have a class extending from active resource as follows:

```
class BookResource < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.book.com:3000/"
end
```

Here is my books_controller.rb

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @book = Book.find(:all)
  end
end
```

Running the following command in rails console:

```
2.1.2 :009 >   BookResource::Book.find(:all)
```

Actually using the above call, it is giving an error called

> "    ArgumentError: expected an attributes Hash, got ["total_entries",
>   38]"

```
2.1.2 :009 >   BookResource::Book.find(:all)
I, [2015-02-25T14:04:00.492054 #12622]  INFO -- : GET http://localhost:3000/api/v2/books.json
I, [2015-02-25T14:04:00.492197 #12622]  INFO -- : --> 200 OK 5489 (50.0ms)
ArgumentError: expected an attributes Hash, got ["total_entries", 38]
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1327:in `load'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1074:in `initialize'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1001:in `new'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1001:in `instantiate_record'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:997:in `block in instantiate_collection'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/collection.rb:67:in `block in collect!'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/collection.rb:7:in `each'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/collection.rb:7:in `each'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/collection.rb:67:in `collect!'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:997:in `instantiate_collection'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:966:in `find_every'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:873:in `find'
    from (irb):9
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/diya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@verve-offers/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.1.2 :010 >
```

Comment: Why not `@book = Book.all` ?

Comment: Nice. I never knew about this - http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-find

Comment: Tried using @book = Book.all returns the same error

Comment: Can you post an actual responds from `http://localhost:3000/api/v2/books.json`.